# Phpmetrics don't generate any data

Tags: php, metrics

I'm trying to learn how to use phpmetrics but I'm stuck.
After executing command:

```
php phpmetrics.phar --report-html=symfony_metrics.html symfony_clean
```

The symfony_metrics.html file is generated, but when I open it I'm getting message:

> No Data Available.

Answer (score 0):

- does the "symfony_clean" folder contain any PHP file ?

  - What is the version of PhpMetrics (phpmetrics.phar --version)
  - what version of PHP do you use ?

Thanks

Comment: "symfony_clean" contains many .php files, it's simply symfony 2 framework app.
- Phpmetrics version 1.4.1,
- PHP version 5.5.12